# Атомный и ядерный

Tags: синонимы

Сейчас вопрос не к физикам, а все-таки к знатокам русского языка.
Иногда говорят "ядерная энергия" или "ядерная бомба", а иногда - "атомная энергия" и "атомная бомба" (чаще). Но при этом я ни раз не слышал, чтобы говорили "ядерная электростанция".
Скажите, пожалуйста, слова "атомный" и "ядерный" (не в физическом, а в лингвистическом смысле) - синонимы или все-таки нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, разделение в употреблении слов сложилось по идеологическим причинам: когда-то в прессе принято было противопоставлять т. н. "мирный атом" ядерному оружию (критика навязанной нам гонки вооружений и т.п.). В меньшей степени это связано с расширенным техническим смыслом слова "атомный".

Атомные электростанции, атомные ледоколы и даже подводные лодки - то что в бытовом сознании ассоциируется с безопасным использованием атомной энергии, не связанным с ядерным взрывом (неконтролируемой ядерной реакцией).

В случаях, когда использование атомной энергии связывают с опасностью, практически всегда, напр. в оф. документах по безопасности атомных станций, говорят о чём-то "ядерном". Ядерная безопасность атомной станции, ядерный реактор, ядерное топливо, ядерные отходы, ядерная авария на атомной станции, ядерное оружие, ядерный удар.  В английском такого разделения нет: атомная станция - буквально "ядерная" (nuclear power plant).

Answer (score 1):

Ядерная и атомная энергия-синонимы.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/42667

Ядерная энергия (атомная энергия) — это энергия, содержащаяся в атомных ядрах и выделяемая при ядерных реакциях.

Атомные электростанции вырабатывают эту энергию, это название появилось первым, оно и осталось.

Атомная бомба — авиационная бомба с ядерным зарядом.Это первоначальное название авиационной ядерной бомбы, действие которой основано на взрывной цепной ядерной реакции деления. С появлением так называемой водородной бомбы, основанной на термоядерной реакции синтеза, утвердился общий для них термин…

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/793686

Answer (score 0):

Ядерное оружие — взрывное устройство, где источником энергии является деление **атомных ядер**.

Так что, к бомбе оба понятия применимы, но синонимами сами по себе они не являются.

Answer (score 0):

> Скажите, пожалуйста, слова "атомный" и "ядерный" (не в физическом, а в лингвистическом смысле) - синонимы или все-таки нет?

Нет. Это разные понятия.
Даже если ограничиться физическим смыслом, то все равно нет.

Но в Ваших примерах "атомная" и "ядерная энергия" являются полными синонимами, образовавшимся св силу исторических причин (так тогда понимали), "атомная" используется чаще, но при этом "ядерная" безусловно более правильно с точки зрения физической сущности явления.

Что касается "бомбы", то тут надо разбираться по контексту. Тут тоже исторические причины вмешались.
"Атомная" может означать любую бомбу, использующую эффект ядерного распада-синтеза, в том числе и дейтериево-тритиевый ("водородная" бомба). А может только основанную на термоядерном распаде трансурановых элементов (т.е. частный случай предыдущего).
Ядерная бомба - чаще относится все-таки к последнему случаю (хотя это тоже не соответствует физическому смыслу). 
Так что тут лучше прямо или по контексту уточнить у автора, что он имеет в виду.